# How to get this data store notation to draw data flow diagram in Microsoft Visio?

Tags: microsoft-visio, notation

I am drawing data flow diagram and I found that the notation of data store to draw data flow diagram in Visio is not what I want.

This is the default data store notation:

[image]

This is what I want:

[image]

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It's in the "Gane-Sarson" stencil, but you need Visio Pro. There are free stencils available if you search for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have these shapes as a commercial offering:
http://www.paulherber.co.uk/visio-dfd/